# Pass pipeline variable to release variable Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops

Created CICD pipeline with trigger release, and Pipeline variable set in to Azure Devops Rest API. Getting variable in pipeline and set Output true using PowerShell.

```
 Write-Host $(webAppName) 
echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=webAppName;isoutput=true]$webAppName"
```

And set the release pipeline variable using
WebAppName= ${{variables.webAppName}} on the variable tab. It's not working, don't have idea how can we retrive the pipeline variable in release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The is no official way to pass variables from Build to Release.

Using Variable Groups in Azure Pipeline Library is a good option: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/variable-groups?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

Another work around, you could store the variable values in a file and attach that as a Build Artifact. That way you can read the file in the release pipeline by downloading Build Artifacts and set the variable again. You could check my answer here: [is there any way to pass variables from CI to CD pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72626413/is-there-any-way-to-pass-variables-from-ci-to-cd-pipeline/72627074#72627074)

Comment: Thanks for your update, Actually it's dynamic variable. So used update variable REST Api, to update the variable. It's works, Thanks.